# Wiki mirror missing wiki pages

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

None of the wiki pages seem to be available on mirrors (see [this mirror](http://mirror.clarkson.edu/ros/wiki.ros.org/) for e.g.). When I try to follow the [mirroring instructions](https://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors#Mirroring_the_wiki), none of the actual wiki pages are downloaded. Has anything changed in the wiki mirroring scheme?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356931/wiki-mirror-missing-wiki-pages/) by [V C](https://answers.ros.org/users/35561/v-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-07-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-03-31**:
Indeed I do see similar/same even today. Reported https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/mirror/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I confirm. Mirrored Wikis allmost are empty. I don't remember in which log I saw the error. But it was somehow connected with "/var/www/wiki.ros.org/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages". I tried to look for a solution a few weeks ago, but I gave up and forgot about this problem for a while. And now I can't remember where that log with errors is.

---

Originally posted by [EDE](https://answers.ros.org/users/19506/ede/) with karma: 36 on 2020-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0